# Opening a file which is a symlink in Python

Tags: python, symlink

I have some python code that opens a file to read it like so...

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

On MacOS, if `file.txt` is a symlink - Python will follow the symlink and read the target file. However, on Windows it does not do this - how can I achieve this?

(Using Python version 3.6.5 and Windows 10)
Steps to reproduce.

1. Create `FileA.txt` in `DirectoryA` which is above `DirectoryB`
2. Inside `DirectoryB`, Run `mlink FileA.txt "../FileA.txt"`
3. Run a Python script which attempts to read and print from the `FileA.txt` link in `DirectoryB`

Expected Behaviour:

The contents of `FileA.txt` inside `DirectoryA` should be printed

Actual Behaviour:

`OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'FileA.txt'`

Comment: What does it do instead?

Comment: @Shadow It just blows up saying the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace of this to your question - it'll help.

Comment: I can't right now I don't have access to a windows machine

Comment: Can you also add the python version to the question? 2.7.x?

Comment: @BhathiyaPerera done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something else has gone wrong. I strongly suspect that you're not running this from the directory that contains `file.txt`.

I'm using Windows 10, and Python 3.6.

Here I am creating a file (using trusty notepad). I added some text to the file during the first line, and verified that it was present in the second.

```
cd c:\
notepad test.txt
mklink other.txt test.txt
notepad other.txt
```

Now over to python...

```
f = open("C:\\other.txt")
f.read()
```

This all worked for me. More details will be required in order to assist you, but as it stands your problem is not reproducible.

---

Now that you've updated your question with exact steps I can tell you exactly what's going wrong.

But first - try opening that file in notepad (or anything else).

> It won't open - instead it'll give a file error.

This is because of the path you've given it. Windows uses `\` for directory seperators - but you've used `/` to create the symlink. This symlink points to an invalid filename. Python is nice enough (being crossplatform) to convert it for you - but windows does no such thing.

Try your instructions again - but this time use `mklink FileA.txt "..\FileA.txt"`

Comment: Can you try with python 2.7? Because that's what I was using.

Comment: It might be more interesting to have you do it. Try following the steps I've outlined. If it doesn't work, please add what you did and the output to your question.

Comment: Another difference was that my symlink was pointing to a file one directory up using a relative path (..). Does that work for you? Maybe it's only working because the link is pointing in the same directory.

Comment: I would be very surprised if it made a difference. A symlink might as well be the actual file as far as standard operations are concerned. You'll need to update your question with a verifiable example - otherwise I cannot help you further than I already have.

Comment: I just tested and it does make a difference. In your command try `mklink other.txt "../test.txt"` and see if it works for you. I get an OSError from python when I try to read the link saying Invalid argument: '<my link name>'

Comment: Still works my end - please update your question with exact steps to reproduce this problem.

Comment: Okay I updated my question with the reproduction steps.

Comment: @Ogen I think I see the problem. See my revised answer.

Answer (score -1):

I don’t do MS Windows.  But this might help: http://winshell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortcuts.html

Does your version of MS Windows actually support symlinks? Or are you dealing with these “shortcuts” (Shell links)? Does it actually have a .lnk extension?

Comment: I doesn't have a `.lnk` extension. I'm using the `mklink` command in Windows to create the symbolic link.