# Python `open` for a symbolic link on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, symlink

Are Windows 10 symbolic links supported by Python 3?

I've created a symbolic link using `mklink` on Windows but when I call Python's `open` on it, I get a message that the file does not exist.

Note that this is not a *shortcut* Windows file (which is of course just a regular file with redirecting information that Windows Explorer uses), but a *symbolic link*.

I expected this symbolic link to be treated transparently by the file system, that is, that the file system would give access to the target file to any application (including Python) accessing the link. Isn't it how it is supposed to work?

Comment: This question is from before Windows 10, but worth checking out: [Symlinks on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1447575/4518341)

Comment: Note that this question looks similar, but it turned out to be user error: [Opening a file which is a symlink in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50321207/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea: Though it might turn out to be the same error; we need a [MCVE] from the OP.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Agreed, an MRE would help greatly. Also just to be clear I'm not necessarily suggesting a duplicate, just some resources OP could check out.

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate of "Opening a file...". Same user error! Namely, bad usage of mklink with a relative path. In those cases, the link is relative to the symbolic link's path, not to the path where the mklink command is executed as I had assumed. Thank you!